# ios SDK command-line tools

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, sdk

For some reason, I can't find the (official) documentation on the iOS SDK's command-line tools (such as xcodebuild). For xcodebuild there's a [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html), but I was looking for something more complete, including (hopefully) other tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xcode installer installs command-line tools in `/Developer/usr/bin`. I haven't checked but I'd guess that every important tool in that folder has a man page with more info.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't find there the tool I was looking for (something that installs an updated provisioning profile), but this is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for xcodebuild on the iOS developer site from Apple and cannot find anything substantial. So I have started searching Safari Books Online and I have found a few books which go into build automation and continuous integration which is what I want to learn about in more detail.

Even searching documentation in Xcode via the Organizer shows minimal information. You may have more luck in the Developer Forums which require a login.

https://developer.apple.com/devforums/

Beyond documentation it may also help to find working build scripts. A search on GitHub for xcodebuild in shell scripts reveals many matches. You may find something useful there. I will be digging there myself.

https://github.com/search?langOverride=Shell&language=&q=xcodebuild&repo=&start_value=1&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93